# Dealing with "missing" data when adding new features later

Tags: data-mining

The conditions:

i have dataset with 2 feature

everyday i collect new data. so the rows is increased

i have collected data for 1000 days, so i have 1000 rows

i've added new feature (feature 3) in day 900

i cant get past data.

the problem is i have different rows:

feature 1 and feature 2 have 1000 rows

feature 3 has 100 rows

what is the best solution ? should i do imputation ? should i make multiple subset ?

i think the condition will be occured again because i have  a plan to add new feature again in the future  (feature 4,feature 5, etc)

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution that is best for everybody.

In some cases, it may be fine to just discard the old data.

Imputation is probably not a good idea. I'd rather use an algorithm that can just ignore missing values.